# How to time remap faster than 1000% in Premiere

Tags: premiere

Is there a quick and easy way to time remap faster than 1000% in Adobe Premiere CC 2017?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try nested sequences.  Insert your video in a sequence, speed it up the maximum amount.  Insert that sequence into another and then speed up the original sequence.  Note that the impact will be multiplicative, so if you make the video 10 times faster and the sequence 3 times faster, you'll end up with footage 30 times faster than the original.

Answer (score 2):

Simply right click on the clip in your timeline, and select ***Speed/Duration...*** and in the dialog box that pulls up, simply enter the length you want the clip to be in the ***Duration:*** field.
[image: Premiere Speed/Duration screen shot]

From my experience, I have been able to go up to 10,000% without nesting, doing it this way.

Comment: While this does work, the limitation of the approach means you can't speed ramp or ease the time remapping at the beginning or end.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a fix but I have a very simple work around that will allows me up to 10000x, simply change the 'speed/duration' setting of the clip to 1000%, then using the time remapping and ramping tools as normal. Make the normal speed areas 10% (10% of 1000 equals 100%, normal speed) and then speed up areas by what you want, 500 or 1000% will be equivalent to 5000 or 10000 percent. You just have to think of it all scaled down by a factor of ten. Hope this helps someone! I'm very happy with how simple this makes my edits and find this is fast enough speeds for my needs. Cheers, Bill

Comment: This is actually the correct answer that allows for smooth ramping, but this is really annoying, does anyone know if DaVinci allows this? Might be time to finally switch anyway..